# How to match source files in multiple subdirectories with a list and then copy to destination using powershell

Tags: powershell

I seem to be going round and round with this one and I don't have a lot of time. I want to copy files from multiple subdirectories to a destination. Now the requirement is that these files must match what I have on a list. These files have different extensions. See what I tried below:

```
$source = "C:\pike"
$destination = "c:\pike2"
$filter = get-content 'C:\same.txt'
Get-ChildItem $source -recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $filter } |   Copy-Item -Destination $destination
```

Comment: `Where-Object { $filter -contains $_.Name }`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `-match`, use the `-contains` operator to test whether the name is in the `$filter` array:

```
Where-Object { $filter -contains $_.Name }
```

---

In PowerShell version >= 3.0, you could also use the `-in` operator:

```
Where-Object { $_.Name -in $filter }
```