# Powershell 'cannot bind argument to parameter' error when using answer

Tags: windows, file, powershell, runtime-error

The most popular answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338097/remove-lines-from-file1-that-exist-in-file2-in-powershell) involves the following Windows powershell code:

```
$file1 = Get-Content C:\temp\file1.txt  
$file2 = Get-Content C:\temp\file2.txt   
$Diff = Compare-Object $File1 $File2  
$LeftSide = ($Diff | Where-Object $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=').InputObject  
$LeftSide | Set-Content C:\temp\file3.txt
```

Yet when I try to use that code, I get the following error:

`Where-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilterScript' because it is null.`

Why am I getting this error, and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a simple syntax error.  `Where-Object` requires the conditional filter to be presented as a scriptblock (hence "FilterScript"):

```
Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That fixed the bug.  Now, the bigger question... why doesn't it work?  Always getting a 0 byte output file.

Comment: I'd check $Diff and make sure you're actually getting LH side differences from your Compare-Object.

Comment: Do you have time to discuss this in chat?

Comment: Not right now (I have burgers on the grill), but if you're having problems with the Compare-Object results, just post another question and somebody will probably chime in.

Comment: Thank you.  Toss one on the grill for me too! :)